# DIV-Elemt absolute(!) positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

First for all: No, I'm not looking for the property position: absolute;

What I want to is to create a field that displays some text. I want to display that field exactly in the middle of the page and then fade out the background, doesnt matter, where the div is placed in the code.

At the moment it looks like that:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wiljdh1xjj3we1c/Capture1.PNG
https://www.dropbox.com/s/chw7pdes5fdcj3u/Capture2.PNG

How can I place an Elemtn ABSOLUTE in the middle of the page, doesnt matter where it is written in the code?

Now I could just say well, I will place it on top of the content. But the problem is, in this field is displayed some information that generates in the content, so I have to put it in the code after the content.

I hope, someone can help me :)

PS: If you have another solution to solve something like this... feel welcome to tell me! I just want something like an alert();-Box with my own style.

EDIT: Some effort: (basically already shown with the screenshots, but here some code; just didnt want to make it confusing)

I save the text as following:

```
// Save Help-Text
ob_start();
?>
This is the main page. There is no help available!
<?php
$help = ob_get_clean();
```

I display the text as following: (echo create_help($help); creates the help-tag and displays it)

```
function create_help($content){
$help = "
<div id=\"help-bg\" class=\"closehelp\" ></div>
<div id=\"help\" >
    <img src=\"../images/close.png\" class=\"closehelp\" />
    $content
</div>
";
return $help;
}
```

This is the CSS for the box:

```
/* Help-box style */
#help 
display: none;
position: absolute;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: #B8DBFF;
border: 5px solid rgb(58, 100, 250);
border-top: 30px solid rgb(58, 100, 250);
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 20px;
width: 600px;
z-index: 1001;
#help img
position: absolute;
margin-left: 595px;
margin-top: -47px;
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
/* Makes background of Help-box transparent black */

#help-bg 
background-color: black;
z-index: 1000;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
opacity:0.6;
display: none;
```

Comment: First show us some effort. Where's your code attempt?

Comment: You *are* looking for the property `position: absolute`, you are also looking to make sure none of the element's parents have the property `position: relative` or looking to make sure that that element is only ever a direct child of body.

Comment: You're attempting to reinvent the wheel when a wheel is the perfect solution to your problem. Put your alert box code in a location where it is the direct child of the body and use absolute positioning. Any other solution is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @Brian Ray That is what I said in the explanation... I cant put it as a child of the body because it contains text/code that generates during the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would recommend using `position:fixed;` instead of `position:absolute;` because the alert would scroll within the page. If you have a fixed height and width try something like 
`margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;`. This CSS-Code will center your div horizontally and vertically (Demo -> http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/demo.html). But if you are using an dynamic height maybe you should consider using jQuery or give it a fixed top position.

Comment: I think you exchanged something... with position:absolute; it stays at the same spot. If I have a lot of stuff in the help-box so that it is bigger than the screen I WANT to scroll down to see the bottom part... Anyway: Thans for your post!

Comment: Hm ... it shouldn't stay at the same spot (shame on me) because last time I created a popup this code worked just fine. But I really think a fixed position is nicer: You could give your popup-content a max-height and overflow-y:auto. So when your content is too large you can scroll within the content of the popup instead of scrolling the whole page. But that's just my opinion (and the way I did it last time). I hope the project you are developing will be successful! And thanks for answering and correcting me!

Comment: I also already thought about an overflow-property, but I tried it but it didnt work as I wanted... So I just "fixed" it with using position: absolute and then you just can scroll down without having a scrollbar. Therefore the "background" (the main page that is faded out) also scrolls with... but thats no problem...

Comment: If the background is outside your popup you could give the fixed-property just to the background without affecting your popup. But as long as your background doesn't have any gradient or image it doesn't really matter. A little tip: You can achieve cool-looking results by blurring the page content with css (and animating it) and giving the popup a little bit of opacity - this is what I made recently: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/qfjothwqvqkadv4/popup.jpg

Comment: Oh, that actually looks really cool... thanks for that tip...
Can I probably get your code of just for the box? (probably just the CSS style)

Comment: I will try to create a demo page for this popup dialog tomorrow (Unfortunately I don't have any time left today and it's already evening where I live) with all its source code included (you may play around with it and use it in your project of course)

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try to use that for my project... But it looks almost the same as mine :P (the programming part) Did you use my crapy stuff or did you already had it like that?

Comment: Litte bit bug-report:
Sometimes of you open the box a second time it doesnt work anymore...
Also: It looks aweful (messed up with the positioning and that stuff) in the IE 11 - works fine in firefox

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! But unfortunately I won't have enough time to be able improve the popup or fixing the bugs (Messed up titlebar in IE and disappearing of the dialog after reopening it to quick). Did you also test it in Chrome, Safari or Opera? Because sadly the blur doesn't work in Firefox (To get it work with Firefox I would have to add an SVG-Blur instead of just -webkit-filter:blur(10px);). To your question: I didn't use anything of your code; I wrote my code a few weeks ago for a little project I'm working on and cut it out yesterday to but it on a demo page for you. :-)

Comment: Thats no problem, you dont have to fix it. Just that you know.
No, I just have Firefox and IE, cant test it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
html, body{
  position: relative;
}
.yourAbsoluteClass{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT! I dont know why I didnt thin about that... It worked :) Thanks.